# how to know from Option[Map[String,Seq[String]]] contains key or not?

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, collections, playframework

I want to know the `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded` contains `deviceId` or not.

```
val formValues=request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
val number = formValues.get("mobile").head
var deviceId ="deviceIdNotFound"
if(condtion) //thats the problem
deviceId= formValues.get("deviceId").head
```

is there any way of conatins or any other function for `Option[Map[String,Seq[String]]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd strongly encourage you not to use `formValues.get("whatever")`, in part because the syntax is highly confusing—it looks like you're calling `get` with a key argument (as for example on a map), when really you're calling `get` on the `Option` (which is an unsafe operation—you should stay away from `get` on `Option` basically always) and then `apply` on the resulting map (also unsafe). This muddle is Scala's fault, not yours, but you still want to avoid stepping in it.

Instead you can use `exists` on the `Option` together with `contains` on the map. Here's a slightly simplified example:

```
val containsKey = formValues.exists(_.contains(key))
```

This will return `true` only if the `Option` is non-empty *and* the map it contains has the key.

An even better approach is to avoid the `if`-statement like this:

```
val os: Option[Seq[String]] = for {
  m <- formValues
  v <- m.get(key)
} yield v

os.foreach { v => \\ do something with the value }
```

Here we end up with an `Option` that contains the value pointed to by `key` if the original `Option` is non-empty and the map contains that key.