# remove first and last Element from scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

[I am trying to convert my way of getting values from `Form`, but stuck some where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204907/how-to-get-from-optionmapstring-seqstring-contains-key-or-not/24205706#24205706)

```
val os= for {
  m <- request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
  v <- m._2
} yield v
```

`os` is `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String]` and when i print it in console

```
os map println
```

**console**

```
sedet impntc
sun
job
03AHJ_VutoHGVhGL70
```

i want to remove the first and last element from it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `drop` to remove from the front and `dropRight` to remove from the end.

```
def removeFirstAndLast[A](xs: Iterable[A]) = xs.drop(1).dropRight(1)
```

Example:

```
removeFirstAndLast(List("one", "two", "three", "four")) map println
```

Output:

```
two
three
```

Comment: although it looks good, isn't this answer problematic? It seems as if the list is being copied twice: 1. `drop(1)` copies the list without first element. 2. `dropRight(1)` copies it without the last element.

Comment: @MaxG No, because `drop` on a linked list doesn't involve any copying.

Comment: Note that if your `Iterable` has at least 2 elements, you could use [`init`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#init:Repr) and [`tail`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#tail:Repr) to select respectively all elements except the last and all elements except the first: `List("one", "two", "three", "four").init.tail`

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use `slice`.

```
val os: Iterable[String] = Iterable("a","b","c","d")
val result = os.slice(1, os.size - 1) // Iterable("b","c")
```